# node.js and npm has no network access in windows 7 64 bit ultimate

Tags: node.js, windows-7, npm

NOTE: to anyone else who has this problem, I tried all suggestions and all research. In the end I formatted the hard drive and reinstalled windows. Even though it was a fresh install from the start some windows installations just appear to not work at all with node. As far as I know this is the only solution.

So to start with, I already found the similar question:
[Basic Node.js examples not working on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553937/) which seems to be the same issue but there is no solution. I have also found forum posts online with no solutions but many people posting the same issues.

`Node.exe` and `npm` both appear to have no network access. `npm install` sends the get requests and never get a response. Node scripts that go to access a mongodb never send the connection request. I copied this code from my old machine to my new one. It was the first thing i put on the new machine. The old machine was running windows 7 64 home premium and the new one windows 7 64 ultimate. I've tried all compatibility modes, running as administrator, disabling windows firewall, there is no antivirus yet, i uninstalled/reinstalled, and I've tried changing the versions even though the version from old computer to new are the same. I've searched stackoverflow and the internet and have found others with the problem but no solutions. I have a virtual box ubuntu vm that can run node successfully however I would like to be able to run it without a vm if possible and I can't seem to find any cause of the problems. Even OEM software between the two computers are nearly identical since the old was an alienware m15x and the new is an m14x. Any help is appreciated.

edit:

I'm using the latest version currently (0.6.10). After running npm install and having it hang, i used `netstat` and got the following results under node.exe:

```
 [node.exe]
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49690     ec2-107-20-159-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https                       ESTABLISHED
  [node.exe]
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49691     nuq04s08-in-f31.1e100.net:https  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49692     fa-in-f94.1e100.net:https  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49693     nuq04s08-in-f19.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49696     nuq04s08-in-f25.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49702     nuq04s08-in-f6.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49703     nuq04s08-in-f25.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49704     nuq04s08-in-f25.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49706     nuq04s08-in-f26.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49707     nuq04s08-in-f26.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49708     nuq04s08-in-f26.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
   TCP    10.20.21.225:49709     nuq04s08-in-f26.1e100.net:http  TIME_WAIT
```

Now when I run the example server on the node.js homepage, I cannot get the hello world in the browser however the connection is in netstat:

```
  [node.exe]
   TCP    127.0.0.1:1337         Robbie-PC:49805        ESTABLISHED
  [node.exe]
   TCP    127.0.0.1:7789         Robbie-PC:49158        ESTABLISHED
```

but when i wait a little while it changes to:

```
  [node.exe]
   TCP    127.0.0.1:1337         Robbie-PC:49805        CLOSE_WAIT
  [node.exe]
   TCP    127.0.0.1:7789         Robbie-PC:49158        ESTABLISHED
```

edit 2:

so I tried disabling all other connections.. no luck. Then I tried to use the debugger in eclipse, even eclipse couldn't find the vm's debugger broadcasting on port 5858. It literally just has no connection. So unless someone finally has any other ideas aside from wiping the hard drive and reinstalling windows, then I think this computer is going back to alienware as DOA. lets hope the next one doesn't have this problem. Thanks to all those who suggested things in the comments and to everyone who attempted to investigate a solution for me.

Comment: What version of Node.js?

Comment: What version of `node.js`? What happens when you run the simple little HTTP server script in the linked question? Does `netstat` (or the Windows equivalent, if it isn't named `netstat`) show the server listening? Which clients don't work? Can you use `telnet` or `nc` or a similar program to connect to the fake server? Does it fail only for the `http` module or does it fail for other pre-packaged `node.js` servers?

Comment: just updated the post with all this info

Comment: I am having this exact problem. A PC running Windows XP on the exact same network works fine.

Comment: Have you try internal node.js debugger: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/debugger.html ? (Note: I have Windows 7 64 Ultimate and node.js works fine to me)

Comment: I have not but what exactly should I be looking for in the debugger

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one network point available? Like wireless and ethernet and maybe node is getting confused? Also is ipv6 enabled on those?

Comment: ipv6 is not enabled and there are multiple networks (wireless and lan) however I have the same setup on another computer with many networks (wireless, lan, bridges, and vm adapters) and it works fine on that. Later on I'll try disabling all but wireless and see if that changes anything. Also its worth noting that I do use google chrome which seems to work fine with the v8 engine.

Comment: so I tried disabling all other connections.. no luck. Then I tried to use the debugger in eclipse, even the debugger couldn't find the vm's debugger broadcasting on port 5858. It literally just has no connection

Comment: What is your firewall situation?

Comment: No 3rd party firewall (computer is just out of box) and I tried both disable windows firewall and permitting node in it, neither worked

Comment: In explorer, open the directory containing node.exe, right click on node.exe and go to properties.  There may be a box checked that says something like "unblock node.exe". Also, I know you said you disabled the firewall, but did you specifically add node.exe as an exception?  Just because the firewall is off does not mean that the ports are open.

Comment: If all else fails try completely removing node and re-installing it.  That worked for me with a similar problem.

Comment: tried to add as an exception and i tried to disable the firewall. There is nothing about unblocking it. Tried removing and re-installing different versions. And I've tried running as admin and in all compatibility modes.

Comment: Suggestion for better response is to post the same query in here : https://github.com/joyent/node/issues

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a corporate network which probably needs proxy configuration on node to be setup. It runs something like this

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Replace the proxy company name to whatever your network uses.

Comment: I wasn't behind one but thanks for the suggestion. Reinstalling the OS from scratch fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

With the same OS I don't have this problem, but I already have problems downloading some packages (I wanted node mysql). In order to fix that I had to download the source from [github](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), extract it in the node_modules repository and to rename it as "mysql".

Now I can make `var mysql = require('mysql');`

Comment: That will work for me to get the packages but the packages still don't have network connection. Initiating a basic http server uses internal node packages only and should work out of the box so my issues are a little more complicated than that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe even try cygwin. Its a step back from both pure virtual Linux, and from getting it to run on Windows 7. Personally I have both Cygwin and Windows 7 installs of node.js on 64 bit (not ultimate though).

I just had to install node to a directory outside of 'program files' due to write protection and security settings. Still have to run the command console as administrator though to make sure all things work. Cygwin has none of these issues.