# node.js express not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was making a node.js web server on my laptop and it worked without problems. After moving it to my desktop it stopped working because the request was always timing out. After trying to get it to work I decided to try a new script but the request kept timing out.

This is what I tested

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

I have tried disabling my windows firewall and avast but it didn't do anything. I also reinstalled node.js and still have this problem.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port number, maybe something else is already running on that port.

Comment: what's your request looking like?

Comment: @George I have and got the same result

Comment: does your call back on the listen method ever fire? do you see `Example app listening on port 3000!` in your console?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code - running this locally works fine. Since nobody will be able to reproduce your problem, it's just guessing on our part why it's not working.

Comment: @JayLane Yes, it does fire but the app.get doesn't seem to fire for some reason

Comment: you're doing a get request to localhost:3000 via a browser or via a client like insomnia or curl?

Comment: @JayLane I'm using chrome but I also tried Edge

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code at all i copied it straight into a file and ran it and the request works fine... i'm stumped. What happens when you try to access via Chrome? Just a white page? or you get a 404 or request took too long error?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553937/basic-node-js-examples-not-working-on-windows-7

Comment: @JayLane It gives the timeout page that says ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: @JayLane did not work for me

Comment: and you have tried completely shutting off windows firewall? do you have any 3rd party anti virus or anything else that could be interfering with access to the ports on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

So I thought that maybe I should restart my pc even if I didn't think it would help. But restarting fixed the issue and now it works as it should. Thanks to everyone for helping.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try to add "res.end()"; after the "res.send('Hello World!')" ?

Comment: res.send sends the response you don't need to use res.end